# What is the best way to load web resources [js, css, images] when changed

Tags: javascript, html, css, optimization, web

Im facing a problem regarding the browser caching of resources. There are a few javascript files, css files that are changed continuously, though the timing is not fixed.

When i update those files on the server, the new files are not loaded and the browser cache needs to be cleared in order to load the new files.

Is there a way, a server or browser setting to tell the browser, when loading a resource, if there are any changes in the server file, load from the server , else use the existing file stored in the browser cache.

---

Im looking for a solution that would require some browser based / server based configuration, and not something i need to manually do everytime i make an update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using just a query string to bust cache is not 100% guaranteed: for example some proxy servers will strip any query string on files linked from your html.

A better way is to revision in the uri or filename.  I use rewrite rules in apache so that something like:

my.app.com/12345/js/file.js

Is directed to:

htdocs/js/file.js

in the filesystem.

My app then updates the revision number based on source control, but you could do this by hand in your html.  With this solution and setting a far-future expires (http 1.0) and max-age (http 1.1) header I get the benefits of permanent client caching via a new uri, and the development ease of the file being in the same place on the filesystem.

Steve Souders on far-future headers:

http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2008/08/23/revving-filenames-dont-use-querystring/

Answer (score 4):

Just put ?[Some unique/random number] at the end of url it will get file every time .

for instance

http://abc.com/css/mystyles.css

make it like

http://abc.com/css/mystyles.css?123163

Time ticks could be one of the best option instead of random number

Comment: there are more than 10 resources, and i think it would be tricky to keep a track (changing the numbers) everytime i update the resources..

Comment: you do not have to remember the numbers, ? and after it will be ignored by browser you can use Random numbers method on server side where you include the files

Comment: You don't need to keep track. Just use randomly generated number at the end of URL

Comment: You could have this number be generated automatically on the server each hour/day/week/month/whatever suits you. It doesn't really have to be a random number either, you could have a script check when the file was last edited and append that date.

Comment: I'd avoid query strings as proxy caches generally won't cache resources with them in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way, a server or browser setting to tell the browser, when
>   loading a resource, if there are any changes in the server file, load
>   from the server , else use the existing file stored in the browser
>   cache.

To achieve the above, you can [Configure ETags](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags). But this will not avoid the cost of a http request hitting the server as a cached file would.

**UPDATE**

From [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10171755/what-is-the-best-way-to-load-web-resources-js-css-images-when-changed#comment13051578_10171956) you can do something like this

```
<?
function get_filename_with_version($fname)
{
    return "?filename=" . $fname; // Generate the hash of the content and append it here as a query string
}
?>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="resrc.php<?php echo get_filename_with_version('a.css');?>" />
```

Comment: can you tell me how would i add headers for a single resource file like.js , in php

Comment: i read about Etags and last modified header, but im a bit confused how i would be using it for specific resource files

Comment: i dont want to put that check on the root file, but on individual resource files.. does that mean i need to load them dynamically like 

<link rel="stylesheet" href="resrc.php?filename=a.css" />
and add the headers there.

Comment: Why are the static files served through resrc.php?

Comment: heh, thats my question, how to set the Etag , last modified header to static resource files

Comment: @NaumanBashir the resources are served using one single resrc.php file and not directly. if using resrc.php you cannot use etags.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good practice to design your site so that the client only needs to fetch external JavaScript and CSS once.

Set up external resources to expire 1 year in the future. Append a version number to each file name, so instead of "stylesheet.css", use "stylesheet-1.2.4.css" and then when you want to update the client's CSS, increment the version number.

Incrementing the version number forces the client to download the updated file because it is seen as a totally separate resource.

and if you don't want this solution then do this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheet.css?foo=<?php echo rand(); ?>"/>
```

or

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheet.css?foo="Math.floor(Math.random()*1000)>
```

Comment: Why would you want to include a random number? Isn't that just going to lead to extra downloads an totally defeat the aim of caching resources?

Comment: I think you did not read the question? that is what the response is required in question sir. Please review and try to understand the question.

Comment: The question asks how to get the files to download when they have changed. Using a random number will mean the files are downloaded every time whether they have changed or not.

Comment: sir there are two solution in answer if you read the first one, it is as you are saying 2nd option is conditional as I said in post If you don't want this solution then do this.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way, a server or browser setting to tell the browser, when loading a resource, if there are any changes in the server file, load from the server , else use the existing file stored in the browser cache.

try to use cookies to check that.

Answer (score 0):

If you work with PHP you can use this solution:

```
//Just add the timestamp as parameter to your filename.
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css?<?php echo time(); ?> />
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/script.js?<?php echo time(); ?>"></script>
<img src="image.png?<?php echo time(); ?>" />
```